# The design of widgets has changed

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-calendar-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm working on apps script gmail add-on. Today the design of addon has suddenly changed. All widgets look different. Sometimes it seems like the styles are not loaded. No mentions about any design changes in google documentation.
For comparison I opened different add-on's in different browsers, workspaces and gadgets. Here is summary:

1. Add-ons in mobile versions have familiar design (as shown in [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets))
2. Add-ons in calendar workspace also have old design.
3. All add-ons in gmail workspace have changed design in different browsers (Chrome, Safari)

Here is screen-shot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3gm2.jpg) example of 2 views of one addon (1 - new view; 2 - old familiar ):

Tried to logout, reload. No changes.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this in the end? I have the same issue

Comment: It fixed itself. But now it has reappeared for no apparent reason. I've added the issue report in google issue-tracker. I'll notify you if the situation clear up.

Comment: Would you be able to share the issue report? Sorry mine still hasn't resolved

Comment: @EdwardTaylor it looks like Google changed this design forever. They documented it: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Google team has already [documented the new widget design](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/widgets). Now it is clear that the UI in the Addon needs to be remade, the appearance of widgets will not remain the same.